# Does aggregation in ES works on all the docs(with query match all) in es index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aggregation

Let's suppose I have 10^6 docs in my Es index . Will aggregation work on  all the docs to get results .

```
GET myindex/_search
{
 "size":0,
"aggs":{
"Unique_term":{
"terms":{
"field":"category",
"size":"10000"
}
}
}
}
```

Also the distinct terms I want to get are less than 10k .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the terms aggregation will give you the result where buckets will be built based on each unique value from the `category`

If no `size` param is set then by default it returns only 10 buckets

Comment: It will work on all the docs even the number of docs is 10^6 to get unique categories ??

Comment: Yes @AkshaySharma terms aggregation will give you unique terms even for 10^6 documents